# How is SO started up, how is the traffic brought up?

Tags: discussion

How the marketing job was done in old days?

Comment: You mean how was it launched and brought to the public?

Comment: Yes,that's what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO started up with the readers of [Joel's](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/) and [Jeff's](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/) blog. These blogs are pretty popular.

Comment: A good point.Are you a guy of SO?How many guys are there in SO?

Comment: Define            "guy".

Comment: staff of this company?

Comment: Founders: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4 -- Employees (I think): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3 -- Advertising guy: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/133733

Comment: Nope, I'm not. Here is your answer:: http://stackoverflow.com/about